# Hive/SparkSQL - Type Coercion from date to timestamp in an expression

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

When I run Hive queries in Spark SQL, **LHS** (`timestamp`) `<=` **RHS** (`date`) for same value `'2013-09-30'` **is not treating as equal**. Whereas `CAST` of `TIMESTAMP` in RHS works well.

```
> SELECT CASE
           WHEN CAST(ADD_MONTHS(CAST('2013-09-30' AS DATE), +1) AS TIMESTAMP) <= ADD_MONTHS(CAST('2013-09-30' AS DATE), +1) 
            THEN 'less than or equal'
           ELSE 'greater'
       END AS TIMESTAMP_LTE_DATE
FROM
VALUES(1);
+---------------------+--+
| TIMESTAMP_LTE_DATE  |
+---------------------+--+
| greater             |
+---------------------+--+
```

We have so many expressions with `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` combinations more over all the queries will generate dynamically. So, difficult to find and `CAST` columns or values in all the places.

Is there a way to Automatically convert RHS/LHS in expression to the higher data type(**Type Coercion**) in Hive/SparkSQL ?

Tried similar query in Oracle 11g as well and it works fine which goes to `equal`.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: New answers with diff solutions(if spark resolves it next version)/hack is always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [type coercion rules for `TimestampType` / `DateType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/TypeCoercion.scala#L330-L334) comparisons are hard coded and convert both sides to `StringType`:

```scala
// Comparisons between dates and timestamps.
case p @ BinaryComparison(left @ TimestampType(), right @ DateType()) =>
  p.makeCopy(Array(Cast(left, StringType), Cast(right, StringType)))
case p @ BinaryComparison(left @ DateType(), right @ TimestampType()) =>
  p.makeCopy(Array(Cast(left, StringType), Cast(right, StringType)))
```

and with lexicographical ordering date representation date representation goes before timestamp representation for the same date.